# Android USB without ROOT permission

Tags: android, usb, root, libusb

I am working on an Android application which talks to webcam over USB.

I am using JNI to use the device libraries (*.so files). The application itself is in USB host mode and is working as expected on a custom image where I give read-write permissions to all the users for accessing USB device in /dev/bus/usb/

The app in not able to communicate with the device in a stock image where the device is not rooted.

is there a way a for the device to be able to communicate without root or custom image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way, but it's a bit tricky.

you need to sign your application with the same key as the os is signed with. 
which allows you to get system permission without using rooted device.

you can try reading through this [android permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html).

and you can get more detailed description from this [posted question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647547/android-usb-automatically-grant-permission/33555752#33555752)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).