# How to grant Android USB Permission Automatically without a popup in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I was sent to the following stackoverflow topic to have this occur from Xamarin forums (thanks David Hunt!):

[Android USB Automatically Grant Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647547/android-usb-automatically-grant-permission)

This appears that I would have to be have this completed in Java with Android and then a Jar file will have to be created so this can be utilized in Xamarin correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a class in your android project that does this. You would just have to convert the Java in the example into C#. That is far easier than writing it in Java, creating a binding, and then consuming it in your Xamarin app.