# Grant USB permissions as device owner

Tags: android, android-usb, android-management-api, android-enterprise

A [device owner](https://developers.google.com/android/work/terminology#device_owner_do) can grant [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions) to a third-party app using [DevicePolicyManager.setPermissionGrantState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setPermissionGrantState(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) to avoid user prompts.

But is there any way for a device owner to grant [USB permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#permission-d) as well, so that this app gets access to plugged USB devices without user prompt ?

I've tried to call `UsbManager.grantPermission()` (with reflection) but it raises a `SecurityException` since it requires the `MANAGE_USB` permission which is granted only to system apps (and not to device owner, obviously).

NB: I'm looking for a solution working on a non-root & non-custom Android system, the device owner app is set using [Android Enterprise provisioning methods](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device).

Comment: Take a look here, if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647547/android-usb-automatically-grant-permission/33555752

Comment: @GauravMall Unfortunately all the suggested answers require to be a system app

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that detail just passed over my head. I don't know how. Did it help you, however?

Comment: @GauravMall Not really. Surprinsingly it feels like an impossible thing to do.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? Even UsbManager.grantPermission() (with reflection)  deosn't work anymore on Android 9 with root system app

Comment: found solution for Android 9 https://stackoverflow.com/a/57622623/7767664

Comment: @user924 this solution requires root access

Comment: @fiddler yes, I know. But it's the only possible solution

Comment: @user924 gives me an error: "W/System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" in "grantDevicePermissionMethod.invoke(iUsbManager, usbDevice,appInfo.uid); "

Answer (score 4):

There is a special system config to disable USB permission dialogs:
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/8ff4a5a5b510e724b25ac00369696594bb0c9fdc/core/res/res/values/config.xml#L2283

Maybe you can also change it at runtime with root privileges using setprop.

Another way is to customize the UsbUserSettingsManager class, specifically this method: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/services/usb/java/com/android/server/usb/UsbUserSettingsManager.java#178

I assumed that as a device owner you have full control over your ROM source code.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a custom ROM and I don't have root access. The device owner app is set using standard [provisioning methods](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device). Therefore I cannot use any of these solutions.

Comment: Maybe your device owner app could declare the appropriate intent filter and react to plugging in of the USB device by calling grantDevicePermission() on UsbManager for a uid of the third party app which it can get in some other way? The idea is similar to what is done in onDestroy() here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.0.0_r1/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/usb/UsbPermissionActivity.java

Comment: I've just tried it, but unfortunately the [UsbManager.grantPermission()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.java#601) methods require the [MANAGE_USB](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#L1700) permission which is only granted to system & privileged app, but not device owner apps.

Comment: Did you manage to find any way to do it without OS source code ?

Comment: Did anyone find an adb prop to toggle this config parameter? It looks like it is built in at build time and not exposed through ADB.

Comment: One could use adb shell setprop persist.sys.usb.config_disableUsbPermissionDialogs true, but on my device it does not work....

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old, but hopefully it helps s.o. else.
I've been using this for granting permission to apps

```
public boolean setPermissionGrantState (ComponentName admin, 
                String packageName, 
                String permission, 
                int grantState)
```

Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setPermissionGrantState(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: AFAIK that doesn't work with USB permissions (I already mentioned this method in my question)